# Implementing Doctrine many-to-many -- sometimes

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a site with many Users and many Designs, each of which was created by one User.  Users can also select other Designs as a favorite, and can go to a page that shows their favorites.  So, there's a many-to-many relationship between Users and Designs termed "Favorite".

I'm wondering what the best way is to implement this Favorite relationship.  I'm only ever looking for Favorites for a particular user, and only on one page.  It seems that Doctrine defaults to returning an object with all its related objects, so I'm concerned that by adding this relationship I'll suddenly get a ton of extra objects added to all my Design list API calls.

Advice on how to set this up?  I have repositories in place for all entities.

Comment: No need to worry.  Doctrine lazy loads by default so you won't get the extra objects unless you try to access them.  You cal also use query builder to load up you objects and specify exactly what you want.

Comment: I guess the query builder is the way to go.  I do a lot of stuff w/ API's and AJAX calls, so not much option for the lazy loading -- everything gets sent in the JSON API call for the client's use.  That's why I get all the extra data -- taking the objects returned from findBy() and converting straight to JSON.

Comment: Extra Lazy Associations: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.0.x/tutorials/extra-lazy-associations.html can also be helpful if user has a lot of favorites

Answer (score 0):

I'll share an implementation I have between Tags and Posts (Posts can have multiple tags, and each tag can be associated with more than one post). I think it's similar enough to get you started. It's super simple to setup:

In the Post entity, I have this:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tag", inversedBy="posts")
 * @JoinTable(name="activity_relationship",
 *      joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="object", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="subject", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $tags;
```

In the Tag entity, I have this:

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Post", mappedBy="tags")
 */
protected $posts;
```

There no entity necessary for the joining table.

In the case of posts carrying tags, it's enough for me to just access the tags property since there will always be a small amount, but each tag is likely to have tons and tons of posts, so I want some LIMIT and OFFSET controls over this. For this reason, as Cerad mentioned above, you don't need to use the $posts variable directly, instead I query that separately using dql.

```
SELECT t
FROM Post p 
JOIN p.tags t 
<add whatever other stuff you want>
```

Whichever way you prefer to execute that query, you will probably have a query object from Doctrine, to apply the LIMIT and OFFSET, just do

```
$query->setMaxResults($limit);
$query->setFirstResult($offset);
```